# Namespaces in Inherited Web.config ignored during Razor compilation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, sitefinity

I have a Sitefinity project using MVC4 with inherited web.config files in subfolders of the root Views folder that import namespaces specific to a controller's models. This was working before and I don't know what changed, but it isn't working anymore and I'm left scratching my head. The setup is something like:

```
- Views
  - MyController
    - MyView.cshtml
    - Web.Config
```

Then in the web.config I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="MyController.Models" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
            <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Which is simple enough. In my views in that subfolder, I get full Intellisense recognition of my class (hovering over `@model MyModel` says `class MyController.Models.MyModel ...` so I know that VS is picking up the additional namespace).

But when I compile the project and request that page, I get an exception:

```
Type : System.Web.HttpCompileException, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Message : e:\TEMP\root\35d89ea4\b5299118\App_Web_index.cshtml#mylayout.cshtml.11a9a948.hv-sp9as.0.cs(160): 
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

TargetSite : System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults Compile()
Stack Trace :
    at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
    at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
    at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath)
    at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass4.<GetPathFromGeneralName>b__0(String path)
    at System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.GetDisplayInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, String virtualPath, Func`2 virtualPathExists)
    at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath>b__8(IDisplayMode mode) ...
```

So if I go in and open the compiled page's files in the ASP.NET temp directory, I can see that my namespace isn't included in the `using` statements, hence the "type or namespace could not be found" exception.

What could have possibly happened to cause this to stop working? And how do I fix it? There are other developers working on the project as well, but after diffing through revision history nothing really seems to be any different. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Interesting to note, if I add the Razor using statement `@using MyController.Models` at the head of the view, it's all gravy. I was just trying to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was tracked back to a bug in the Sitefinity related extension Feather. The github issue can be viewed here:

[Namespaces in Inherited Web.config ignored during Razor compilation #2190](https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather/issues/2190/)

Also, a Sitefinity forum post about this issue can be found here:

[Namespaces in Inherited Web.config ignored during Razor compilation](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/bugs-issues-/namespaces-in-inherited-web-config-ignored-during-razor-compilation)